# Cannot read property 'Mixin' of undefined Ember Validation

Tags: node.js, ember.js, yeoman-generator

I am using yeoman generation of ember app.

I've installed ember-validations using the following line in dependencies, bower.json file.

```
"ember-validations": "http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/ember-validations-latest.js"
```

Then I ran

```
bower install
```

This is how I am using the validator in the controller

```
Client.UsersCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin);
```

But when the server starts the following error appears in the console:

```
Cannot read property 'Mixin' of undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll need to put a `<script>` tag in your HTML to include `ember-validations`.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, I've added but the problem persists `<script src="http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/ember-validations-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: No, you don't put in scripts from a CDN- that is why you are using `bower`.  You'll need to use the template html file generated by `yo` and put the script tags in the commented location.  You will have something like `<script src="bower_components/ember-validations/...">`